# Prove that $G$ is the semidirect product $U\rtimes{D}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Let be $k$ a field and $G$ the group of the triangular superior matrices
in $GL_3(k)$. Prove that $G$ is the semidirect product $U\rtimes{D}$, where $U$ is the set of upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal and  $D$ is the set of diagonal matrices in $GL_3(k)$.

My path: I tried to say that every semidirect product is determined by the choise of homomoprhism $D \rightarrow Aut(U)$. Such homomorphism is determined by its value on a generator of D, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to continue the proof, any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean that $U$ is the set of triangular matrices with $1$s **on** the diagonal. If they are the set of upper triangular (the more common English term) matrices, but you have $1$s *under* the diagonal, then they aren’t triangular anymore, and they are not closed under products.

Comment: You're right, sorry, bad translation

Comment: Since both $U$ and $D$ are subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_3(k)$, this is a case of an *internal* semidirect product, not an external one. The action of $D$ on $U$ is by conjugation inside of $\mathrm{GL}_3(k)$. You should verify that $D$ normalizes $U$ and intersects it trivially. Then you will need to show that every element of $\mathrm{GL}_3(k)$ can be written as a product $AB$, with $A\in U$ and $B\in D$.